# ddbstreams to opensearch via NodeJS lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

Wanted to sync up the **AWS Opensearch** with **DynamoDB** table data.

I'm triggering my Lambda function via dynamodb streams and wanted to save it in **AWS Opensearch** via **AWS Lambda**. I wanted to do it in **NodeJs**, but everywhere on internet I can found only **Python** examples.

My **DDB** table has the following attributes
`id`, `name`, `color`, `price` (example: `0000car1000`, `Toyota Camary Hybrid`, `Green`, `27,000`)

In **AWS Opensearch**, I wanted to search on `name` attribute.

I'm easily able to get the new data in Lambda, but stuck on how to store that data in Opensearch.

Here is my **Lambda** code

```js
const { OpenSearchClient, AcceptInboundConnectionCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-opensearch");

const client = new OpenSearchClient({ region: process.env.LAMBDA_REGION });

const host = 'search-ddbsearch-yxxxxxxgu.us-east-2.es.amazonaws.com';
const url = 'https://' + host + '/' + index + '/' + type + '/';
const headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"};

const index = 'name'; // expecting ddb table column name would map to name in opensearch
const type = '_doc'; // Not sure what is type

module.exports.handler = async (event) => {
    console.log("DDB Stream event === ", JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));

    for (const record of event.Records) {
        console.log(record.eventID);
        console.log(record.eventName);
        console.log('DynamoDB Record: %j', record.dynamodb);

        const newImage = record.dynamodb.NewImage;
        // TODO: Save newImage in Opensearch
    }
    return `Successfully processed ${event.Records.length} records.`;
}
```

Is there any reference I can follow to make it happen in **NodeJS**?

Comment: Have you come across anything? Surprised AWS doesn't have an example in Node.

Comment: Code and examples are available on the Opensearch documentation site here: https://opensearch.org/docs/2.7/clients/javascript/index/